# Cómo ingresar una fecha en un JFrame

Tags: java, netbeans

**Código** (publiqué una parte y marqué con un comentario la línea que me interesa):

```java
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   Docente objDocente = new Docente();
   objDocente.setId(Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText()));
   objDocente.setNombres(txtNombre.getText());
   objDocente.setApellidos(txtApellido.getText());
   objDocente.setSexo(txtSexo.getText());
   objDocente.setEstado(Boolean.parseBoolean(txtEstado.getText()));
   //objDocente.setFecha_ingreso((txtFechaIngreso.getText());  
   //     ^^^^^^ Acá es donde quiero ingresar la fecha
   //objDocente.setFecha_nac((txtFechaNacimiento.getText());
   objDocente.setEmail(txtEmail.getText());
   objDocente.setTelefono(txtTelefono.getText());
   objDocente.setDireccion(txtDireccion.getText());
   int numeroFilasAfectadas=FDocente.insertar(objDocente);
    if (numeroFilasAfectadas>0) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"INSERTADO CORRECTAMENTE");
    } else {
         JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"INSERTADO INCORRECTAMENTE");
    }
}
```

Alguien me puede explicar cómo ingresar una fecha en el `jFrame` para mostrar en una base de datos.

Comment: ok ya le edite y le puse como texto al código, soy nuevo aqui,una  disculpa

Comment: Que tipo de dato es Fecha_nac, que tipo de dato es en la base de datos? Como la ingresas en la vista?

Comment: en el código es de tipo date y en la base de datos Fecha_nac también tambien es  de tipo date y la quiero ingresar mediante un JtextField

Answer (score 1):

No se como viene la fecha de tu base de datos. Pero supongamos que viene con un formato yyyy-M-dd. O si no, adapta a tu necesidad. En este ejemplo ponga la fecha actual, pero dentro del JTextField agrega lo que viene de la base de datos.

fecha_nac es tu fecha_nac de la respuesta de tu consulta de base de datos.
En tu select coloca lo siguiente:

SQL:

```
DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac, '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha_nac
```

Java:

```
// Panel.
JFrame panel = new JFrame("JPanel en Java");

String pattern = "yyyy-M-dd";
SimpleDateFormat formatoDelTexto = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date fecha = null;
try {
    fecha = formatoDelTexto.parse(fecha_nac);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
}
JTextField fechaNacimiento = new JTextField(fecha.toLocaleString());

// Se agrega en un JTextField fechaNacimiento al panel.
panel.add(fechaNacimiento);
```

Comment: en la base de datos fecha_ingreso y fecha_nac están definidos como date y en el código también

Comment: @cristianmunoz entonces dentro de tu JLabel agrega en vez de new Data lo que viene de tu base de datos y en el pattern el patrón que esta en tu base de datos.

Comment: pero le quiero ingresar en un JTextField

Comment: @cristianmunoz JTextField fechaNacimiento = new JTextField(formatDate.format(new Date())); Mejora la respuesta

Comment: aca esta unas lineas de codigo con la cual tambien estoy intentado se inserta todo, pero en la base me muestra vacio las fechas             String text = txtFechaIngreso.getText();
//       SimpleDateFormat sdf;
//       sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
//       java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(sdf.format(text));
//       objDocente.setFecha_ingreso(date);

Comment: @cristianmunozen un text que te imprime??

Comment: la fecha me debe de imprimir pero no se a muestra en la base de datos las fechas, me muestran vacias

Comment: @cristianmunoz en la base de datos no muestra la fecha? al recuperar la fecha de la base de datos no muestra nada??

Comment: me muestra todo excepto las fechas me aparece vacio la de fecha_Ingreso y la fecha_nac

Comment: @cristianmunoz entonces es algo de tu base de datos. que tipo de dato es la fecha_Ingreso y la fecha_nac de tu base de datos. Date o String??

Comment: es de tipo date tanto el código como en la base de datos

Comment: @cristianmunoz ahi mejore la respuesta. Deberia de funcionar. En tu select tenes que poner DATE_FORMAT(fecha_nac, '%Y-%m-%d') as fecha_nac

Comment: @cristianmunoz si haz solucionado, podrías poner solucionado por favor. gracias.

Comment: no lo solucione me sale error ya estoy investigando porque me sale ese error pero gracias por la ayuda